# Using Enhanced Link in Enhanced Einstein Bot

Tags: servicecloud, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots, bots, chatbot

I have an Enhanced Einstein Bot that utilizes Dynamic Enhanced Links, and it functions properly. However, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to pass an ImageId to the bot.

You can either utilize Dynamic Title, Dynamic Image, and Dynamic URLs, or use constants to display the standard Enhanced Link. The problem arises when I provide the Id of my ContentAsset to the Enhanced Link; it ceases to function altogether.

I'm uncertain about what I might be doing wrong. When I utilize the Enhanced Link by only passing the title and URL while using the constant image, it works just fine. However, as soon as I attempt to include the ImageId (extracted from ContentAsset), the Enhanced Link fails to display.

I have also used ContentVersion Id, ContentDocument Id but nothing seems to work.

There is also no documentation for passing a dynamic image, it just tells you it's possible, but doesn't show you how.

For reference:
[image: Variables]

I have created a variable within the Messaging Component, which will be populated when I pass the value from the Einstein Bot, which I got from an Apex Action.

Subsequently, I use the parameter in the image Configuration:

[image: Parameters]

Unfortunately, despite these efforts, it fails to display the image I've passed to the Messaging Component.

Can anyone help me please?